# Is a Console Application & Windows Form Application combination possible?

Tags: console-application, windows

I use Visual Studio 2010 and am coding in C#. A couple of people I know have a difference of opinion on what format these programs should be in, console or windows form. These programs usually just install\delete\modify\create other files given some settings and files already provided to the program.

The reasoning for the console application is to have the ability use it in batch scripts for unmanned execution and repetition with different settings. The reason for the Windows Application is ease of use instead of typing command line options and arguments. Is it possible to combine both of these or is it even a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do, given the right values, can be pulled out into a shared project then yes. You then have two more projects: the console app, and the windows app. Both of these take a reference to the shared project with the meat of the logic. The app projects are there to give an interface into the shored project.

Personally, if the app is just going to use values given to it I'd give it a config file and make it a console app that pulls from that config. You could then have it set up differently on different servers. You could even put different named configuration in that file and have the console app do nothing but ask with named config to use. If the app can be a console app and it is for use by programmers/admin/other power user type people, then it is likely it doesn't really need a windows UI over it.

Comment: As of right now, your second paragraph that you wrote, is the current setup we are using.